# Why can't I change the current locale when testing Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, locale

I have a multilingual application and I am trying to write some tests for one of my controllers. However, it seems that I cannot change the current locale in testing. It works ok in development. Assume that my test is as follows:

```
test "do something has to be done correctly" do
  I18n.locale = :cn # set current locale to chinese
  assert_equal :cn, I18n.locale
end
```

This test fails with error:

```
<:cn> expected but was
<:en>.
```

`:en` is the default locale in my configuration.

Has anybody encountered this problem in Rails 3 before? Any solution found?

Comment: what if you overwrite the default_locale?

Comment: After your comment, I have tried `I18n.default_locale = :cn;assert_equal :cn, I18n.locale;` and it fails with the same error message.

Comment: ok and `I18n.default_locale = :cn;assert_equal :cn, I18n.default_locale;` ?

Comment: This works. But this does not solve/answer my problem. I want to change the CURRENT locale not the DEFAULT locale. In my application, I change the CURRENT locale by setting a new value to `I18n.locale` and it works fine. I do not know/understand why this does not work in test environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, inserted precisely as you have it in a functional test case, works perfectly in a new Rails 3.0.9 application.

That having been said, setting the locale in `I18n.locale` within a functional test before calling `get` or something to test a controller is **not** going to set the locale in your application's context (only the locale in your test's context).

Usually you need to merge something like `{ :locale => :cn }` into your parameters, to set the locale for your request.  This won't affect the actual test you're showing, but maybe you're not showing precisely what is failing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am working on UNIT test and not FUNCTIONAL test. You are right that I had to clarify this from the beginning. Hence, my case is that it does not work on UNIT test. Do you have any clue why? Can you replicate? BTW, I am using Rails 3.0.7.

Comment: You said you were writing a test for one of your **controllers** - that can't be a unit test.  In any case, the same code in a 3.0.7 app unit test works fine too.

Comment: (I said that I was wrong about controllers testing). I have started a brand new application and created a single model. Then tested and it works. You are right that it works fine in brand new application. Hence, I have to find the reason why it does not work for the existing application that I have.